# In Java Script Text box Name Doesn't like

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to change my text box name in Form because it' using some where else in program.

Problem is JavaScript doesn't like my textbox name **(m4j-117)**. it's Considering "-" as minus.

How can I make it work with out change my text box name.

Thanks

Any help will be appreciate.

Here is my Sample Code.

```
 <form name="randform">
 <body>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



 function randomString() {
   var chars = "0123456789";
   var string_length = 8;
   var randomstring = '';
   for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.randform.m4j-117.value = "P"+randomstring;
}
</script>


<input type="button" value="Create Random String" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="name" value="value" onblur="randomString();;"/>
<input type="text" name="m4j-117" value="">
</body>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.randform['m4j-117'].value
```

Relying on names is a bit antiquated though; I'd suggest giving it an ID and using `document.getElementById` directly, or using `querySelector` with an appropriate ID for the form

Comment: +1 but what is it you don't like about using form/input names? The top line of code seems both short and descriptive to me.

Answer (score 11):

How about:

```
document.getElementsByName("m4j-117")[0].value = "P"+randomstring;
```

From a specific form:

```
document.randform.elements["m4j-117"] = "P"+randomstring;
```

Comment: Gabe @ what about my from name i don't need that.?